# New custom record should Automatically get created whenever Opportunity record gets created

Tags: process-builder

I have tried in process builder on Opportunity.There is a PM-I record type on Opportuntity, Whenever PM-I Opp gets created Child custom object (Appointment__c) should be automatically created. Please find the attachements.New record is not getting created.Some times it is throwing error.PFA[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You say this Appointment is a child of Opportunity. So you need to explicitly set the field value of the lookup from Appointment -> Opportunity to equal the current Opportunity's ID. Otherwise it won't appear in the related list of the Opportunity.

Overall though we don't have enough info to judge why sometimes it throws an exception. Remember that Process Builder is not very tolerant of nulls, so any time you reference a field from a related object you must ensure you've checked it's null before attempting to look at that field.